# Share on facebook and twitter without page referesh

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I am very confused about sharing to facebook and twitter.

I have a simple javascript game, in which the user answers questions and after answering 3 questions wrong, they are out of lives and have to share this on facebook or twitter to get another life and continue where they left off. For this I want to let them share about the game on their timeline on facebook or tweet about it but I don't want to refresh the current page.

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people in any way for sharing or liking (and “forcing” them to share to get another life falls into that category). Go read Platform Policies please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook and Twitter both have APIs available that will allow you to do that sort of thing. As far as what is required to post to someones wall etc, you would need to read the docs bellow.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

https://dev.twitter.com

In JavaScript you could use an AJAX request to interact with these APIs either directly, or by making a request to a server side script that handles the interaction for you.

Using an AJAX will allow you to make the request and get a response without reloading the page.

You can read more about AJAX here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp, and if you're using jQuery it has an ajax function that really handles a lot of the leg work of making the request for you http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/